# "How'd I come here?" vs "How did I come here?"

Tags: sentence-usage

I found a related post [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114281/meaning-of-howd-you-know-would-did-or-do) but I'm still confused and not sure whether it's correct to use "How'd I come here?".

When search in google I got only about 11 [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22How%27d%20I%20come%20here?%22&oq=%22How%27d%20I%20come%20here?%22&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=%22How%27d%20I%20come%20here?%22&start=10) for "How'd I come here?", but I got about 200 [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22How%20did%20I%20come%20here?%22&oq=%22How%20did%20I%20come%20here?%22&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=%22How%20did%20I%20come%20here?%22&start=210) for "How did I come here?". Why is that? Because this I think "How'd I come here?" is not correct or not acceptable in correct English.

But looking at the other post I mentioned, it seems it's correct and common to say "How'd I come here?". Google doesn't agree with that. What am I missing?

Comment: I think the more common expressions are [“how did I get here?”](https://www.google.com/search?q=“how+did+I+get+here%3F”) and [“how’d I get here?”](https://www.google.com/search?q=“how%27d+I+get+here%3F”)

Comment: “How’d” is not as common as other contractions, presumably because it is more difficult for the ear to detect.

Comment: Google search is not a great indication of relative commonality between words or phrases. I recommend the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) or [Google Ngrams](http://goo.gl/WRPkqX).

Comment: I knew Ngrams, but it doesn't work well if we have special simple like "  or ' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tyler James Young says in his comment, it would be more common to ask, "How did you *get* here?" rather than *come*, and starting your response with the rhetorical question "How'd I get here?" is perfectly natural in casual conversation.

If you were talking about a position/status in life, you'd say something like, "How did I come to be the vice president at the age of 28?" and I think "How'd" would work in informal conversation. If you were talking about a place where you reside (rather than a restaurant or a party, where you recently arrived), you'd also use *come to* as in "How did I come to live here?"

Since the question is rhetorical (I think that's the proper term, since it's a device rather than an actual question for your listener), "How did" sounds like it's  the best overall answer. The dynamics of starting your answer to a question with a question feels more comfortable with a longer answer.